# Loop through Dictionary to find dataType if FirstOrDefault is Null

Tags: c#, types, dictionary

I have some data that comes through and I generate a dataTable based on the type in a Dictionary list of string objects.  The problem I'm having is that the code checks the Dictionary FirstOrDefault to build the datatable, but if any of those values are null things blow up quickly.

Is there a way I can take the following code and iterate through the rest of the dictionary values IF a particular key.Value is Null within those first set of Values to try and find a valid Type?

I tried simply checking and setting the type to string, but IF that column has any real values in it that fails (for instance dateTime when its set to string).  I'd like to loop through all the key.Key type Values in question to try and discover if any of the cells have a type and if they are all null then the string would work.

```
public DataTable(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> source)
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            var firstItem = source.FirstOrDefault();

            if (firstItem != null)
            {
                //foreach (var item in source)
                //{

                //    var u = item.Values;
                //    var t = item.Keys;

                //}
                foreach (var key in firstItem)
                {
                    if (key.Value == null)  //check if value is null and try and find the next value for that key.Key that isn't
                    {
                        foreach (var item in source)
                        {
                            var kk = key.Key;
                            var ik = item.Keys;

                        }

                        //...some logic to try and find if the key.Key Value in question has any legitimate value other than null to set the DataType to


                        //set value to some type here to avoid things blowing up.
                        Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = key.Key, DataType = typeof(string) });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = key.Key, DataType = key.Value.GetType() });
                    }
                }

                foreach (var item in source)
                {
                    var row = new DataRow();

                    foreach (var key in item)
                    {
                        row[key.Key] = key.Value;
                    }
                    Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your method declaration like that or is it a typo?it must be or else it would not compile.

Comment: You have a collection of dictionaries? Your description is confused and your code is convoluted. Can you maybe provide some code that shows what your collection of dictionaries looks like? And explain a bit more clearly what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you start by getting only your keys, and then pull the first non-null value for each key, it should simplify your logic (though it may be a bit more process intensive):

```
if ( source != null )
     {
        var keys = ( from d in source
                          from k in d.Keys
                          select k ).Distinct();
        foreach ( var key in keys)
        {
           //...some logic to try and find if the key.Key Value in question has any legitimate value other than null to set the DataType to      
           var thisKey = key;
           var valueNotNull = source.FirstOrDefault( dictionary => dictionary[thisKey] != null );
           var colType = valueNotNull != null ? valueNotNull[thisKey].GetType() : typeof( string );


           dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn()
           {
              ColumnName = thisKey,
              DataType = colType
           } );

        }
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was a LINQ way to iterate through the incoming dictionary.  I've got to start working on learning it better.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you are trying but about the datacolumn beeing null and finding the next that has the same key replace your foreach:

```
foreach (var item in source)
{
     var kk = key.Key;
     var ik = item.Keys;
}
```

With this:

```
var notnul = source.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContainsKey(key.Key) && x[key.Key] != null);
```

And since we know its a datacolumn:

```
Columns.Add((DataColumn)notnul.Values.First());
```

and this  `var row = new DataRow();` will get you in trouble,consider doing this:

```
foreach (var item in source)
{
     //var row = new DataRow();

     foreach (var key in item)
     {
          if (key.Value is DataRow)
          {
               DataRow row = (DataRow)key.Value;
               Rows.Add(row);
          }
     }

 }
```

Comment: thx for your help terry.  I needed to iterate through the entire dictionary to determine what each set of data's type was is all.  So if column key 2 had a null value I needed to find the next value for key2 and see if that was null, etc...and either determine they are all null or there is a legit value somewhere down the chain.